# How to filter SQL Server 2008 Profiler Output for a single database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

SQL Server 2008 Profiler always profiles all databases. I want to restrict profiling or output to a single database. How can that be done most easily?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a column output/filter by database name or Id. You have to choose "Show all columns" when setting the trace up.

Comment: I had to show the 'database name' column first, as well

Comment: I had to click the show all columns Check box.

Answer (score 9):

Go to trace properties, then show all columns. Once you have selected DatabaseName you can go into ColumnFilters... and set Like to equal the name of the database you want to filter on.

Comment: You can also click on the column title in the selection grid, will display the Filter dialog and let you set a filter condition.